# Python request ValueError Too many values to unpack

Tags: python

While the below data is sent from postman with necessary headers I get the right response with status code 200. But when I hit the function from python requests with the same data I get “error. ValueError Too many values to unpack “ from this line ``.
Data:

```
[{
     "phone_number": "data",
     "notification_type": "data",
     "is_success": true,
     "amount": 58,
     "account_no": "data"
}]
```

```
def serve_sms(self, data: dict):
   token = self.token(sms_service=True)
   header = {

       "service-name": "service",
       "service-key": settings.Service,
       "Authorization": "TOKEN " + token
   }
   try:
       requests.post(settings.SMS_SERVE_URL, data=data, headers=header)
   except Exception as e:
       core_log().debug("serve sms request error {}".format(e))
```

I tried changing the “data” inside response with json `json=data` but there I get the status code of 404.

update 0: Full trace

```
http://... /api-service-auth/
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): ....:80
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://...:80 "POST /api-service-auth/ HTTP/1.1" 200 212
DEBUG:connect_core:serve sms request error too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: What's the exact error with trace? I don't see any unpacking here.

Comment: @Carcigenicate updated my question

Comment: can you try json=data[0] or data=data[0]? Looks like the data is inside python list at 0 index. What i mean to say is the data you pass to post should be of the form `data={ .... }`

Comment: @vk-code I need to send this as array

Comment: I think vk-code is right. I can reproduce the error with `requests.post("http://www.example.com", data=[{}])`.

Comment: then you need to pass it like this `data={ 'list': data}`. 'list' should be some actual name that server understands

Answer (score 0):

looks like your JSON format is wrong. Following code worked for me!

```
import requests 

result = requests.post("http://www.example.com", data={'list': [{
     "phone_number": "data",
     "notification_type": "data",
     "is_success": True,
     "amount": 58,
     "account_no": "data"
}]})

print(result)
```

> ```
> C:\temp\python>python3 request.py
> <Response [200]>
> ```

Comment: returning 404 !

Comment: multiple possibilities, your URL is wrong, or data expected is in wrong internal format. but this solves your `ValueError Too many values to unpack ` error